# Non Public Email Address Validation

Tags: asp.net, regex, email

I would like to only allow email addresses which are valid and non public email addresses eg gmail,yahoo, hotmail etc.

Can anyone help me out check for this? Im guessing i would need to use a regular expression but not sure if there is an easier way

Comment: Would you say that a "non-public email address" would be restricted by the top-level domain, such as only including .edu, .gov, .mil?

Comment: do you have a list of non public email providers?

Comment: i dont have a list of public email providers but i can just go with the main ones eg gmail, yahoo, hotmail

Comment: Non-public mean non-free? or email address for a closed group private local domain names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to filter on the top level domain, then you could use something like this:

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.(?:edu|gov|mil)$
```

This will only validate email address ending with `.edu`, `.gov`, or `.mil`.  For instance,

```
bah@humbug.gov <- valid
guy.smiley@gmail.com <- invalid
doctor.who@univ.edu <- valid
person@anything.com <- invalid
```

*Note: these will all assume that the regex option of `Ignore Case` is turned on.*

If you'd also like to allow for two-letter top level domain country codes, like `.fr` or `.ca`, you could add an expression for that like this:

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.(?:[a-z]{2}|edu|gov|mil)$
```

If instead you want to exclude the "big three" email hosts, you could use something like this:

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@(?!gmail\.com|yahoo\.com|hotmail\.com)(?:[a-z0-9.-]+\.?)+$
```

(*this uses look-ahead assertion with the `(?!)` "match if suffix is not present" grouping*) Examples:

```
bah@humbug.gov <- valid
guy.smiley@yahoo.com <- invalid
doctor.who@univ.edu <- valid
person@anything.com <- valid
```

More regex examples for email address validation can be [found here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: I used your answer but modified the reg expression slightly as hotmail as hotmail.co.nz etc ^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@(?!gmail|yahoo|hotmail)(?:[a-z0-9.-]+\.?)+$

Comment: My employer has the same business need to validate the email addresses of created users to make sure they use the domain names they own and not to allow big public domains like gmail.com and yahoo.com. Just to be clear, that regular expression works well. But the list of the domains is really the question. I am searching for best practices of getting a list of the public domains.